# resulting lists to a tuple (as described in the description, using the tuple function) and the resulting tuples need to be in a list

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary, tuples

the below is my code for extracting from list of dictionary and sorted data in tuple

```
def compress(data):
    res = []
    for idx, sub in enumerate(data, start=0):
        if idx == 0:
            res.append(tuple(sub.keys()))
            res.append(list(sub.values()))
        else:
            res.append(list(sub.values()))
    return tuple(res)

data = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
    {"a": 4, "c": 6, "b": 5}
]

print(compress(data))
```

the expected outcome is:

(('a', 'b', 'c'), [(1, 2, 3), (6, 5, 4)])

by my code cannot retunr in the the expected outcome.

Comment: Don't you mean: `(('a', 'b', 'c'), [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)])`?

Comment: `def compress(data): return (tuple(data[0].keys()), [tuple(x.values()) for x in data])`

Comment: @Booboo not, it is required the result to be (6,5,4)

Comment: 6, 5, 4 are the values of keys c, b and a respectively. Are you saying we should use whatever those values are?

Comment: `def compress(data): return (('a', 'b', 'c'), [(1, 2, 3), (6, 5, 4)])` appears to work, although I can't explain why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def compress(data):
    result = []    
    keys = tuple(data[0].keys()) # the keys
    result.append(keys)
    result2 = []
    result2.append(tuple([data[0][key] for key in keys]))
    result2.append(tuple([data[1][key] for key in keys[::-1]]))
    result.append(result2)
    return tuple(result)

data = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
    {"a": 4, "c": 6, "b": 5}
]

print(compress(data))
```

Prints:

```
(('a', 'b', 'c'), [(1, 2, 3), (6, 5, 4)])
```

Comment: so for the expected outcome, it shoule he a list in the tuple for the value, this one is almost there though

Answer (score 0):

should be

```
def compress(data):
    res = []
    for idx, sub in enumerate(data, start=0):
        if idx == 0:
            res.append(tuple(sub.keys()))
            res.append([])
            res[-1].append(tuple(sub.values()))
        else:
            res[-1].append(tuple(sub.values()))
    return tuple(res)
```

Comment: thank you so much. it works now since I can transform my result into tuple in a list. But I am still facing some difficult in sorted function to sort the value as (6,5,4), really appreciate if there is any suggestion on that.

Comment: This produces: `(('a', 'b', 'c'), [(1, 2, 3), (4, 6, 5)])` How is this the accepted answer?

Comment: To sort the second list in descending order, use `sorted(...,reverse=True)`

Comment: My code now is def compress(data):
    res = []
    for idx, sub in enumerate(data, start=0):
        if idx == 0:
            res.append(tuple(sub.keys()))
            res.append([])
            res[-1].append(tuple(sub.values()))
        else:
            res[-1].append(tuple(sorted(sub.values(),reverse=True)))
    return tuple(res)

Answer (score 0):

Using list comprehensions:

```py
def compress(data):
  keys = tuple(sorted(data[0].keys()))
  values = [tuple(d[k] for k in keys) for d in data]
  return (keys, values)

>>> compress([{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},{"a": 4, "c": 6, "b": 5}])
(('a', 'b', 'c'), [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)])
```

### Optional: missing keys

If some keys might be missing from some dictionaries, you can use all keys from all dictionaries, then remove duplicate keys with `set`, then use `d.get(k, default_value)` instead of `d[k]`:

```py
def compress(data, default_value=None):
  keys = tuple(sorted(set(k for d in data for k in d.keys())))
  values = [tuple(d.get(k, default_value) for k in keys) for d in data]
  return (keys, values)

>>> data = [{'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a':11, 'b':12, 'd':14}]
>>> compress(data, 0)
(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), [(1, 2, 3, 0), (11, 12, 0, 14)])
```

### Optional: another way to store this data

You can refactor this list of dictionaries into a dictionary of lists:

```py
def refactor(data):
  keys = data[0].keys()
  return { k: [d[k] for d in data] for k in keys }

>>> refactor([{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},{"a": 4, "c": 6, "b": 5}])
{'a': [1, 4], 'b': [2, 5], 'c': [3, 6]}
```

Again, you can be careful about missing keys:

```py
def refactor(data):
  keys = set(k for d in data for k in d.keys())
  return { k: [d[k] for d in data if k in d] for k in keys }

>>> refactor([{'a':1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}, {'a':11, 'b':12, 'd':14}])
{'d': [14], 'a': [1, 11], 'c': [3], 'b': [2, 12]}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I created what you wanted, you can put it in a function, if you want

```py
data = [
    {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3},
    {"a": 4, "c": 6, "b": 5}
]

keys = [[],[]]
for d in data:
    items = list(d.items())
    l = []
    for i in items:
        l.append(i[1])
        if i[0] not in keys[0]:
            keys[0].append(i[0])
        else:
            continue
    keys[1].append(tuple(l))

keys = tuple(keys)
```